# Can I replace rows in an HTML table with new rows, on the click of a button, WITHOUT USING AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an array of 500 arrays. I want to display this 2D array as an HTML table in such a way that only 10 rows are displayed at a time. Initially the first 10 rows are displayed. Then when the user clicks a button labelled `Next`, the first 10 rows are replaced by the next 10 rows, and so on.

My mind is thinking that I will assign the `Next` button a Javascript function as the value of its `onclick` attribute. I will display the first 10 rows initially. Then when the user clicks the `Next` button, the JS function is executed. Inside that function, I will have to use AJAX to fetch the 2D array (which contains the data to display), so that I can display the next 10 rows.

**The question I am asking here is that is it possible to do this entire thing WITHOUT AJAX?**

***Addendum:*** The 2D array containing the data is coming from a table in a MySQL database, if that matters.

Comment: *The question I am asking here is that is it possible to do this entire thing WITHOUT AJAX?*  Provided you are loading the array of array on page load, yes.  Dynamic content does not equate to ajax.  It can, but it does not have to.

Comment: What do you mean by **WITHOUT AJAX**? Have loaded all 500 rows at first time?

Comment: Without using ajax and without having to refresh all page, all relevant data would have to be loaded on first load which could dramatically slow it. But for sure it is possible. Other way would be to set table inside an iframe but you have better to just use ajax...

Comment: Please don't YELL.

Comment: @Chris Emphasizing, not yelling!

Comment: @Azim Yep, right now that's what I have done. It's very slow and sluggish as well. But I now want to display only 10 at a time.

Comment: @Solace, that's what `_underscores_` are for. They generate `<em>` tags, which are literally [for emphasis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em), or `<i>` tags. All-caps, unless it's for something like HTML, SQL, or AJAX, is [generally considered yelling](http://netiquette.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_number_2_-_Do_not_use_all_caps).

Comment: @Solace Italic text doesn't catch my attention the moment I lay eyes on a piece of text, I kinda have to _properly_ read the blob of text and only when I encounter italicized text while I am reading, I realize that the blob of text contains italicized text. Unlike that, I just subconsciously read bold or capitalized text the moment I lay eyes on the page with that text. Is it just me? 
The point of writing this comment is that, I think making text bold or capitalized saves the reader's time I guess?

Comment: So technically, either load everything on the page at once, or fetch partial data. partial data is a http request ( ajax?).. where's the problem? Do you see a third contender here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Ajax when you want/need to dynamically fetch some data from somewhere else (such as your server). Since those 500 arrays are in a MySQL table on your server, clearly you will have to fetch them at some point.

**Option 1.** You could use PHP to fetch all 500 arrays initially and generate the page with it (since the beginning your page will already know all rows). Upside: no need for Ajax since you already know all 500 rows since the beginning. Downside: will be slightly slower to load since you're fetching all 500 rows at once (in my opinion, unless each array is tremendously big this slowness can probably be neglected).

```
<?php
    // Fetch all 500 arrays at once from mysql.
    // I am assuming you already know how to do this
    //     and I'm simplifying the code by just putting a function here
    //     that you'll have to implement, of course
    $array_of_arrays = get_array_of_arrays_from_mysql();

    // Now you have your 2D array in PHP.
    // Let's create the full table, with 500 rows, but set 'display: none;' for
    // all the rows past the 10th, this way the user will only see
    // the first 10

    echo "<table id='myTable'>";

    $arrayLength = count($array_of_arrays); // This will be 500 in your example
    for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++) {
        if ($i < 10) {
            echo "<tr>";
        } else {
            // Create all rows past the 10th hidden since the beginning
            echo "<tr style='display: none;'>";
        }

        // Now we write the cells
        // We have to loop the inner array
        $innerArrayLength = count($array_of_arrays[$i]);
        for ($j = 0; $j < $innerArrayLength; $j++) {
            echo "<td>" . $array_of_arrays[$i][$j] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";

        // Note that we are assuming that all inner arrays have the same
        // length, otherwise the table will be messy, with rows with
        // different sizes.
    }
    echo "</table>";

    // OK, so your server will generate the HTML with the full table
    // but only showing the first 10

    // Now we have to code javascript to change the visibility of the rows accordingly.

?>

<input type='button' value='Next' onclick='goNext()' />

<script>
    // this variable tells us which row group is currently showing
    var currentlyShowing = 0; // currently showing rows 0 to 9

    function goNext() {
        // First of all, we hide everything
        // I will use jQuery here because it is much easier,
        // but it is possible to do it with pure javascript if you want.
        $("#myTable tr").hide(); // This immediately hides all rows in the table.

        // Now we update our variable
        currentlyShowing = currentlyShowing + 10;

        // Now we show the correct rows (the others will remain hidden)
        // Again I choose to use jQuery because it is much easier
        $("#myTable tr").slice(currentlyShowing, currentlyShowing + 10).show();
    }
</script>
```

**Option 2.** Fetch the rows 10 at a time from the server using Ajax, as the user clicks the button. Upside: divides loading time in parts. Downsides: uses ajax instead of plain PHP (you could say it is slightly more complicated); also, after clicking the button the user might have to wait a while for ajax to respond - so the transition to the next 10 rows won't be instant. Since you don't want to use Ajax, go with option 1. You should be fine, there is nothing too bad about option 1, unless you are really worried about the loading time of your page.

Comment: Thank you so much. Pseudocode will be very useful if that's not inconvenient for you?

Comment: I am using the stackexchange app on my phone, so it might take a while, but I'll try. Just be a little patient please :)

Comment: Typing code on the phone isn't working for me :P I'll have access to a PC in a couple hours, then I'll include the code, sorry about that.

Comment: @Solace there you go. Let me know if you need any further help. Sorry to take long. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well i quick idea come to mind is using GET request 
supposing next button will be as following ,
href="action.php?action=next&page=1
first of all you check of get id is numeric and you save its intval.
if id= 1 then in your php script you run sql query saying select from table values between value1 and value10 ,
if id=2 select from table between value11 and 20 and so on

Comment: I am a newbie, and I don't get you.

Comment: "you check of get id is numeric and you save its intval" - I don't understand this part. What do you mean by `get id`? Do you mean the value of `page` variable in `action.php?action=next&page=1`? Where are you incrementing the said `id`? I don't get this idea. Thank you for answering though.

Comment: exactly You get the value of that id and use it

Answer (score 1):

First thing that is needed to be clarified is that there are two different sides which are handling data.

1. Server Side (MySQL Database)
2. Client Side (The Browser in which you want to show the HTML Table)

And as you mentioned your data is on the server side in the MySQL database, you will first need to transfer that data from server to client.

Now here comes the question that whether you want the data in single pull or you want to pull 10 records at a time which will cause you to call the server side again and again. 
Now you mentioned that you dont want to use AJAX. This means that each time the data is pulled from the database it is going to re-render the page each time so you will see a white blank screen while the data is being pulled. The reason for that is you are calling it on a single synchronized thread. 
On the other hand calling it through AJAX means that you are not disturbing the UI thread.
So you make sure that by avoiding AJAX you are ready to accept that blank screen for a little while. On the other hand you can show some animation for loading time in the AJAX way.
Now for the code part I have a nice little and very simple article to explain you the data fetch from MySQL and showing it in the HTML table.

http://www.djvsoft.com/select-data-mysql/

If you want more details you can also contact me directly on my email address that is Dharmindar@djvsoft.com

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Dharmindar. This time I had to accept the answer by Hamsteriffic because that explained it earlier, but I have just read your article and hopefully will read more of your articles in future. Thank you.

Comment: I am happy that you liked my article. I write on many technologies. You let me know your interest of technologies. I will write for those technologies as well.

Comment: Please find my latest article as below.